# How can I display an image in cython not just in black or white, but with any color I want?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

So, the code below represents my spin field of +1 or -1 elements, as you can see in [the output of the display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jZd1.png).

```
field=spin_field(200,200)


from PIL import Image

def display__spin_field(field):
    return Image.fromarray(np.uint8((field+ 1) * 0.5 * 255))
display_spin_field(field)
```

But, if I now want to include a 0 spin state, so there would be 3 states available (-1,0,1), the 0 element is represented in a grey scale, not too clear to differentiate it from the black or white elements. It would be fantastic if I could represent it in a (for instance) red color, or even the three states in the rgb primary colors, just for full contrast between them. Any idea how could I do that?